# How to get all users - I only get admins?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a list of all users in my organization (~300), but the `/users` endpoint only returns two admin accounts.

Our administrator has given the application consent.

Scope: `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

Does it have something to do with the "(Admin only)" marking on the screenshot below?

[image]

/v1.0/users returns:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some [permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) do require an Admin Consent and thus have the marking "(Admin only)".
"Admin only" means that only an administrator can consent this permission.
Most delegated permissions (access on behalf a user) do not need an Admin consent, but some like e.g. `Agreement.Read.All` are only available for administrators.

[image]

Since you are using Application Permissions (and getting access without a user) all permissions will have the "(Admin only)" mark. But this does not mean that the returned results are limted to admins.

Seeing you have given the app the permission `User.Read.All` your app should be able to request a list of all Users with `/v1.0/users/` (it will definitely return [all users](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users)).

The most likely explanation for your results is that you only have two users in your Office365 AD.
Maybe there was an error setting up the users?
I would suggest to login into the [Graph-Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and check if you get the same results.
And to check in your [Azure Admin Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) if all users registered in your AD.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I am logged in to Microsoft Graph Explorer, I get all the users successfully.

I don't understand what the difference is. Maybe is the tenant id wrong, as sugessted below. In that case how do I get the correct one?

Comment: When you request your token you have to state the tenant in the request Url [doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#4-get-an-access-token): `POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token` + addtional info (client secret,...) in the post body. There you can edit/change the tenant. (but be aware that you may need to aquire an [admin consent](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#3-get-administrator-consent) if not done in before)

Comment: On success you will then receive the token which is a JSON Web Token.
As JSON WebToken is an open standard, 
you can also decode this token yourself and lookup information such as permissions or tenant.
I personally did use for debugging [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) (but its up to you to trust them).

Comment: What is the best approach for getting the tenant id?

Comment: An "AD-Tenant" is an "Id of an Azure Active Directory"  
You can look it up in your [Azure Admin Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) , ([instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-howto-tenant))
or you can look into the response of the [adminstrator consent](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#3-get-administrator-consent) (that is I think is how the Graph Explorer got your tenant id).

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.